# Find values in data frame 2 which is found in data frame 1, within a certain range

Tags: r

I want to find which values in df2 which is also present in df1, within a certain range. One value is considering both a and b in the data frames (a & b can't split up). For examples, can I find 9,1 (df1[1,1]) in df2? It doesn't have to be on the same position. Also, we can allow a diff of for example 1 for "a" and 1 for "b". For example, I want to find all values 9+-1,1+-1 in df2. "a" & "b" always go together, each row stick together. Does anyone have a suggestion of how to code this? Many many thanks!

```
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(10,5)
set.seed(1)
b <- sample(5,5, replace=T)
feature <- LETTERS[1:5] 
df1 <- data.frame(feature,a,b)
df1
> df1
 feature a b
       A 9 1
       B 4 4
       C 7 1
       D 1 2
       E 2 5
set.seed(2)
a <- sample(10,5)
b <- sample(5,5, replace=T)
feature <- LETTERS[1:5] 
df2 <- data.frame(feature,a,b)
df2
df2
 feature  a b
       A  5 1
       B  6 4
       C  9 5
       D  1 1
       E 10 2
```

Not correct but Im imaging this can be done for a for loop somehow!

```
for(i in df1[,1]) {
  for(j in df1[,2]){
    s<- c(s,(df1[i,1] & df1[j,2]== df2[,1] & df2[,2]))# how to add certain allowed diff levels?
  }
}
s


Output wanted:
feature_df1 <- LETTERS[1:5] 
match <- c(1,0,0,1,0)
feature_df2 <- c("E","","","D", "")
df <- data.frame(feature_df1, match, feature_df2) 
df
 feature_df1 match feature_df2
           A     1           E
           B     0            
           C     0            
           D     1           D
           E     0
```

Comment: Can you also include your expected output for the data shared?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Now I have added the wanted output! Number of matches between the data frames. And then a column with which feature it matches in df2. This could also refer to the row number, doesnt matter. Now I realize there can be many matches sometimes, then the output feature_df2 could contain all matching features.  I reduced the data a bit and I diminished the allowed range to deviate to 1. It would be super to be able to change the allowed deviation value within a function, try out different values.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah you often have interesting solutions, Im curious about your ideas in this case:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I loooove `data.table`, which is (imo) *the* weapon of choice for these kind of problems..

```
library( data.table )
#make df1 and df2 a data.table
setDT(df1, key = "feature"); setDT(df2)
#now perform a join operation on each row of df1,
# creating an on-the-fly subset of df2
df1[ df1, c( "match", "feature_df2") := {
  val = df2[ a %between% c( i.a - 1, i.a + 1) & b %between% c(i.b - 1, i.b + 1 ), ]
  unique_val = sort( unique( val$feature ) )
  num_val    = length( unique_val )
  list( num_val, paste0( unique_val, collapse = ";" ) )
}, by = .EACHI ][]

#    feature a b match feature_df2
# 1:       A 9 1     1           E
# 2:       B 4 4     0            
# 3:       C 7 1     0            
# 4:       D 1 2     1           D
# 5:       E 2 5     0
```

Comment: @Wimpel thank you! Its difficult to see whats happening behind this, why are the variables a & changed to i.a and i.b?

Comment: ahahhhh, that is the beauty of the data.table syntax: `DT[i,j]` ;-) What happens in that line is the following: the line iterates through `df1` rowwise (because of the `.EACHI` on the last line. It creates a subset of `df2` on the fly, where `df2$a` is between `df1$a +/- 1`, and since `df1` is added as `i` in the line `df1[ df1, c( "match", "feature_df2") := {`, we can refer to df1 usingi. TLDR; the `i.a` refers to the a value of df1 of the row of the current iteriation. So, we are filtering df2, where a and b are within a margin of 1 of the current a&b value of df1.

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about this in `Base R` would be to split the `data.frames()` into a list of rows then calculate the absolute difference of row vectors to then evaluate how large the absolute difference is and if said difference is larger than a given value.

**Code**

```
# Find the absolute difference of all row vectors

listdif <- lapply(l1, function(x){
  lapply(l2, function(y){
    abs(x - y)
  })
})

# Then flatten the list to a list of data.frames

listdifflat <- lapply(listdif, function(x){
  do.call(rbind, x)
})

# Finally see if a pair of numbers is within our threshhold or not
m1 <- 2
m2 <- 3
listfin <- Map(function(x){
  x[1] > m1 | x[2] > m2
},
listdifflat)

head(listfin, 1)

[[1]]
         V1
 [1,]  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE
 [5,]  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE
 [7,]  TRUE
 [8,]  TRUE
 [9,]  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
  4  1
  7  5
  1  5
  2 10
  13  6
  19 10
  11  7
  17  9
  14  5
  3  5")
df2 <- read.table(text = "
  15 1
   6 3
  19 6
   8 2
   1 3
  13 7
  16 8
  12 7
   9 1
   2 6")

# convert df to list of row vectors

l1<- lapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x){
  df1[x, ]
})
l2 <- lapply(1:nrow(df2), function(x){
  df2[x, ]
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I would also like to know which features this corresponds to, so which features found in df2 also found in df1, depending on settings in diff interval. How many matches was it for each feature, and in which location do I find these features :)

Comment: @user11916948 the object ```finlist``` is more or less the result of a nested loop therefore each ```data.frame()``` within that list compares one row of your ```df1``` with all possible rows of your ```df2```(in order of ```df2```). I will leave the editing of the final output to you :)